# Display cart Grand Total instead of Sub Total

Tags: magento

On my magento theme I have a cart total in the header. 
At the moment it displays the sub total, I was just wondering how I could change this value to display the grand total instead.

This is the code in the template already

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
```

I have tried changing getSubtotal() to getGrandtotal() but it just returns 0.

Anyone got any ideas? 
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can get with `total object`

used my working code to get grand total any where in magento

```
<?php 
 $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
 $grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); //Grandtotal value 
 echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($grandtotal , true, false);
?>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work. http://s10.postimg.org/fnrniz285/Screen_Shot_2013_09_17_at_09_53_54.png

Comment: i have run this code in `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\links.phtml` and it is display grad total when i have any product in my cart just check it.

Comment: Im using the celebrity magento theme and the file I am editing is /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/celebrity/template/checkout/cart/cart-top.phtml 

The current code is in my original post.

Comment: pls try with  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session') i am sure it will work. or check is quote object is available or not ?

Comment: Apologies, it does work but it only shows the figure, so instead of showing '$26.00' then is shows '26'. How can I get it to use formatPrice()? Thank you

Comment: @OliverEvans, pls use my updated answer,pls dont forget to accept my answer and vote up so someone can use our thread for future reference

Comment: Not sure if this is directly related to this question, so if not, please let me know and ill make another question. But basically the grandtotal (in other currencies) seems to be more than my grand total in my cart, I think this might be because its adding a shipping estimate, how can I remove this?

Comment: please see screenshot: http://s23.postimg.org/kbvgyv8wr/Screen_Shot_2013_09_17_at_11_49_34.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37511/discussion-between-oliver-evans-and-liyakat)

Comment: i think you are adding some tax or other charges to checkout please check

Answer (score 1):

Not enough Reputation to Comment so I'm writing this here.

liyakat's answer worked for me on community 1.7 but I don't understand why he wants to round up the numbers.

I wanted to display the exact total (€21.50 not rounded up to €22.00) so I removed "round(" and the last ")" which gives me:

```
        <?php 
         $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
         $grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue(); //Grandtotal value 
         echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($grandtotal , true, false);
        ?>
```

Which works PERFECT!

Thanks a lot, I gave it +1